# Property of custom IdentityUser gets populated with data fetched by an unrelated EF context query

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to understand how the following is possible:

In a asp.net core 3.1 web app, I've defined a custom `IdentityUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public UserSettings Settings { get; set; } = new UserSettings();
}
```

where `UserSettings` is:

```
public class UserSettings
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

The one-to-one relationship is defined using fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserSettings>()
    .HasOne(e => e.User)
    .WithOne(e => e.Settings)
    .HasForeignKey<UserSettings>(e => e.UserId)
    .IsRequired();
```

In the controller with `UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager` injected, I understand that:

```
var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

does not populate the `Settings` property with data from the data store. *(I wonder why, though, because it does fetch data for the `Name` property.)*:

[image]

But if I fetch `Settings` data using the `ApplicationDbContext` directly:

```
var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var settings = _applicationDbContext.UserSettings.SingleOrDefault(s => s.UserId == user.Id);
```

the `user.Settings` property gets populated:

[image]

How is this even possible?

Comment: @PeterB If UserManager has its own DbContext the one-to-one related property shouldn't be updating, should it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usermanager uses the same context, however, when create the one-to-one relationship, query on foreignkey is not executed.

[image]

You need  to eager loading the record so that the settings is fetched.

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var temp = await _dbContext.Users
        .Include(S => S.Settings)
        .AsSplitQuery()
        .IgnoreAutoIncludes()
        .ToListAsync();
```

[image]

[image]

That’s why you can fetch the data through using the ApplicationDbContext directly. Data is not separated, but not loaded.

Here is the document  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

Comment: So, this _"Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded."_ is responsible for this behavior?

Comment: Yes, it is to maintain consistency and integrity between context entities